# Navigation bar/menu not showing in customised colors with Safari (Correct colors in other browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I've made a navigation bar/menu for my website, and I have customised the colors in the CSS. It works fine on IE, Chrome and Firefox. But when it comes to Safari, the navigation bar shows in its default colors! If anyone can help me with this, I would appreciate it greatly.

Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2gtygrc&s=5

Safari:

http://i39.tinypic.com/2eltloi.png

**The HTML:**

```
    <li><a href="index.php?id">Hjem</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=1">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=2">Om</a></li>                
    <li><a href="">Andet</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=3">Kontakt</a></li>
```

**The CSS:**

```
nav ul {
    margin: 80px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0em;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: #1A1A1A;
    background: rgba(26,26,26,.2);
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;    
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(26,26,26,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(26,26,26,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset; 
}

nav li {
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
    padding: .8em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    font: bold 1.1em/1 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d6d6d6 #d6d6d6 #d6d6d6 #d6d6d6;
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#c1c1c1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
    background: linear-gradient(#484747, #2c2c2c);            
 }

nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fac754, #f8ac00);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fac754), to(#f8ac00));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fac754, #f8ac00);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #f5f5f5);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #ff0000);
    background: linear-gradient(#e20000, #720000);
}

nav a:active {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}

nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;            
}
}
```

Comment: Please can we have a fiddle

Comment: Which version(s) of Safari is it not working in?

Comment: The version of Safari I'm currently using is 5.34.57.2

Answer (score -1):

```
nav ul {
margin: 80px 0 20px 0;
padding: 0em;
float: left;
list-style: none;
background: #1A1A1A;
background: rgba(26,26,26,.2);
-moz-border-radius: .5em;
-webkit-border-radius: .5em;
border-radius: .5em;    
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(26,26,26,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(26,26,26,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset; 
}
```

You've got background twice once as hex the other as rgba, I think you only need one.

Comment: I don't personally own all the browsers you're meant to be testing with but try testing it with and without the background styles you don't prefer, maybe you will get the outcome you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks :). I just deleted the rgba. But I still can't figure out, why the color changes to my menu is somehow not compatible with Safari. I'm still trying though.

Comment: The HEX background colour is a fallback value for the RGBa background colour, which will not be supported in some legacy browsers. If the browser does not understand the RGBa value it will simply ignore it and use the HEX value instead. This offers "progressive enhancement", with those browsers that can understand the RGBa value able to take advantage of the additional opacity property, but a usable experience for those that can't. It is perfectly valid to have conflicting property values in CSS, and a  core aspect - the Cascade part of the name. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cascade